# ASP.NET Core MVC - empty string to null when sending JSON to server

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

When posting input data as a `FormData` to the ASP.NET Core MVC controller, by default empty string values are coerced to `null` values.

However, when sending input data as JSON to the controller, empty string values remain as they are. This leads to different behavior when validating `string` properties. For example, `description` field is not bound to `null`, but to empty string on the server:

```
{
    value: 1,
    description: ""
}
```

This in turn makes following model invalid, even though `Description` is not required:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is contrary to the behavior when same data is submitted via form.

Is there a way to make model binding of JSON behave in the same way as model binding of form data (empty string coerce to null by default)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through source code of [ASP.NET Core MVC (v2.1)](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) and source code of [Newtonsoft.Json (v11.0.2)](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json), I came up with following solution.

First, create custom `JsonConverter`:

```
public class EmptyStringToNullJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(string) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string value = (string)reader.Value;
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value.Trim();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }
}
```

Then, register custom converter globally:

```
services
    .AddMvc(.....)
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new EmptyStringToNullJsonConverter()))
```

Or, use it on per-property bases via `JsonConverterAttribute`. For example:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyStringToNullJsonConverter))]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```