# Empty string not being converted to null when passing JSON object to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-core-2.1

In ASP.NET Core 2.1, I'm noticing basically the opposite is happening to this question: [string.empty converted to null when passing JSON object to MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734083/string-empty-converted-to-null-when-passing-json-object-to-mvc-controller)

When I send a `JSON` object back to a controller, that has properties with empty strings, they are no longer automatically being converted to `null`.

For example, take this JS object:

```
 var person = {firstName:"", lastName:""}; 

        $http.post("/app/index", person)
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success
            }, function (error) {
                // Failure
            })
```

When bound to the model in the controller, the properties with empty strings are remaining as empty strings:

```
    //
    // POST: /App
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index([FromBody] AppFormDTO data)
    {
       ....
    }
```

Which when saving this object to the database, I'd prefer to have `null` values instead of a bunch of empty strings.

Did they change the `DefaultModelBinder` in `ASP.NET Core 2.1`? And if so, how do I change it back to how it was in MVC5 -- where `string.empty` was automatically converted to `null`?

**UPDATE**, to add my `AppFormDTO` model, for reference:

```
public class AppFormDTO
{
    public string firstName{ get; set; }
    public string lastName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You were passing empty string not null value.

Comment: Right, but in ASP.NET MVC5, when an empty string was passed, it was automatically converted to null. I'm converting an MVC5 project to ASP.NET Core 2.1, and I'm wondering if I can retain that feature in the new framework?

Comment: You should pass null value or can use property attribute if value is empty then it will be null

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376618/asp-net-core-mvc-empty-string-to-null-when-sending-json-to-server

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your PERSON model for firstName/lastName:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
... the model values
```

Comment: I've tried adding this set to both `false` and `true`, doesn't seem to make a difference, it's still coming through as an empty string instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs) of ASP.NET Core

```
 if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string))
 {
      // Already have a string. No further conversion required but handle ConvertEmptyStringToNull.
      if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
      {
           model = null;
      }
      else
      {
           model = value;
      }
 }
```

The behavior by default is set to empty string to null.
Recheck your model `AppFormDTO` if you putted `ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false` which is not correct.

Comment: I added my `AppFormDTO` model for reference, which doesn't use the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` attribute. Are you able to get it to work correctly? I'm thinking default model binding for a JSON object is overriding this. Specifically the `JSONInputFormatter` mentioned in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1), but I don't know see how to modify it.